# Automate geocode while updating fusion table - google experts

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I want to automate the google map geocoding whenever a fusion table is updated. Or any other webservice to call geocode programatically.

For Ref : please check this image

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/829/7232012113102pm.png/

this is what i exactly need programatically.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not yet possible. There is a [pending feature request](http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=230&q=Type=Feature_Request&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Stars%20Component&start=100), feel free to star it, which shows that you also would like this feature.

Until then you could geocode your data prior to inserting it to Google Fusion Tables. There are several services you could use ([Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/), [Yahoo PlaceFinder](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/), [MapQuest Geocoding API](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/dev-services/geocoding-ws)). Once you got the lat/lng data belonging to your data, you could simply insert it in your Fusion Table.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. This is what i expected.. I have one more doubt, i use a field called "Loc" this is a text field in fusion table. When i click geocode, the markers are plotted in google map. As this field is a text field, where do i need to update my table. None of my table has latitude and longitude field. Am i doing in wrong way?

Comment: You can simply add two more columns to store lat/lng. You then select these as you location columns. If you check the options of the columns you'll see how to do it.